# compare string with double quote

Tags: powershell

I want to compare a string with double quotes. I tried the following code but didn't work.

The sample `$inputStr` is `'{"to":"[Email]","from":"no-reply@mirvac.com","cc":"","bc":""'`

```
$inputStr = '{"to":"[Email]","from":"no-reply@email.com","cc":"","bc":""'
$emailStr = '"[Email]"'
if ($inputStr -like "*"+$emailStr+"*") {
   write-host "exists"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "inverted comma" and "inverted quote"? `'` is a single quote and `"` is a double quote

Comment: @phuclv double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison didn't work because `[` and `]` are [wildcard characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.3) which need to be escaped either using a backtick `` ` `` (`` '"`[Email`]"' ``) or alternatively, with [`WildcardPattern.Escape` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.wildcardpattern.escape?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0):

```bash
$inputStr = '{"to":"[Email]","from":"no-reply@email.com","cc":"","bc":""'
$emailStr = '"[Email]"'
if ($inputStr -like "*$([WildcardPattern]::Escape($emailStr))*") {
   Write-Host "exists"
}
```